# How can I move one Node3D to another Node3D's child in Godot 4.0? And how can I duplicate a random child of a Node3D

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am making some script for a game I'm making. The game's map is a randomly generated series of hallways, and there are different shaped hallways. For example, one hallway is straight, another turns, another turns and has a set of stairs that do down. If there is no way to do anything I mentioned above in the question, is there an alternative?

I haven't really tried anything yet for moving one node to another, because all the tutorials are outdated. For duplicating a random node, I tried something like this:

```
var parent_node = $Node3D
var random_index = randi() % parent_node.get_child_count()
var random_child = parent_node.get_child(random_index)
var duplicated_child = random_child.duplicate()
```

It gave me an error saying `cannot call duplicate on a null instance`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out your problem:
You are trying to get the node: `$Node3D` and call `.get_child_count()` on it before the scene has finished loading. To fix this, add `@onready` at the beginning of each of the lines, or put the in the `_ready()` function. Doing this would make sure the code only runs when the scene is loaded and everything is ready. This is the final code I would suggest:

```
@onready var parent_node = $Node3D

func _ready():
    var random_index = randi() % parent_node.get_child_count()
    var random_child = parent_node.get_child(random_index)
    var duplicated_child = random_child.duplicate()
```

You also said that you want to move the node to another parent node. I will assume you are trying to move the random node. So first lets add another variable for the new parent node:

```
@onready var new_parent = $Node
```

Replace `$Node` with the node you want to be the new parent.

Next we want to add the child to the new parent in the _ready() function:

```
new_parent.add_child(duplicated_child)
```

You are now done unless you want to remove the node from the original parent, then you will add this after:

```
parent_node.remove_child(duplicated_child)
```

This is now the final Code:

```
@onready var parent_node = $Node3D
@onready var new_parent = $Node

func _ready():
    var random_index = randi() % parent_node.get_child_count()
    var random_child = parent_node.get_child(random_index)
    var duplicated_child = random_child.duplicate()
    new_parent.add_child(duplicated_child)
    parent_node.remove_child(duplicated_child)
```

Comment: how can I move one node to another?

Comment: I forgot to add that part to the answer. I will now update it.

Comment: Basicly you just have to assign the node you want to move to a variable, remove it from its parent, and add it to a new one

Comment: so will this work if i instead have the code in another function that is run inside the _ready() function? Example: "func _ready(): function()" and then have "func function(): #codehere"?

Comment: @freddymooney Yes. It should.

Comment: @freddymooney No Problem. Let me know if you have any issues

Comment: @freddymooney Also if this was the answer you were looking for, don't forget to mark it as answered